# Is there a way to mock `process.env.NODE_ENV` in my unit test using webpack and mocha?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, mocha.js, jestjs

I need to to mock in my unit test `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

I am using webpack 2.0 for my build, jest-cli as build runner, and mocha and  testing

```js
import { ENV } from '../index';

describe('environments configuration', () => {
  describe('default environment', () => {
    let config;
    beforeAll(() => {
      delete process.env.NODE_ENV;
      process.env.NODE_ENV = ENV.DEFAULT;
      config = require('../index');
    });

    it('should be default login url', () => {
      expect(config.url.login).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/login');
    });

    it('should store token in local storage', () => {
      expect(config.STORAGE.TOKEN.type).toEqual('localStorage');
    });
  });

  describe('development environment', () => {
    let config;
    beforeAll(() => {
      delete process.env.NODE_ENV;
      process.env.NODE_ENV = ENV.DEVELOPMENT;
      config = require('../index');
    });

    it('should be development login url', () => {
      expect(config.url.login).toEqual('https://dev.localhost.com/login');
    });

    it('should store token in local storage', () => {
      expect(config.STORAGE.TOKEN.type).toEqual('localStorage');
    });
  });

  describe('production environment', () => {
    let config;
    beforeAll(() => {
      delete process.env.NODE_ENV;
      process.env.NODE_ENV = ENV.PRODUCTION;
      config = require('../index');
    });

    it('should be production login url', () => {
      expect(config.url.login).toEqual('https://localhost.com/login');
    });

    it('should store token in session storage', () => {
      expect(config.STORAGE.TOKEN.type).toEqual('sessionStorage');
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seems to do the trick, I always have the default config loaded first.

I have found this [plugin](https://github.com/burl/mock-env) that could eventually do the trick.

Almost none is using so I wonder:

What is the correct way to mock the `process.env.NODE` ?

Comment: Out of interests whats the use case where NODE_ENV would change during a test?

Comment: I wan't to `import { foo, bar, hello, world } from 'config';` This file export some string values that depend on `process.env.NODE`. I want to assert these values.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to test one component as though `process.env.NODE_ENV` is production, but otherwise have `process.env.NODE_ENV` as development so that React prints prop type errors.

Answer (score 4):

You should find after overriding the env vars you can run [`jest.resetModules();`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#resetmodules-boolean) before you import the config. That should then load the config that reflects the expected `NODE_ENV` value.

Without jest you can use the [require-uncached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-uncached) module from npm to achieve the same effect.